# wstring doesn't exist on gcc/c++ v2.96

Tags: c++, gcc

I've a linux application that compiles well in actual Gcc/c++ compilers.

I need to compile it in a very old compiler (gcc/c++ version 2.96). The problem is that wstring doesn't exist.

I look for wstring in all system headers. I found it in g++-3\string but it's commented.

I tried to do a simple Hello world app to test it.

I put typedef wstring but when I do a c_str() of a wstring object compiler said that it can't convert const char * to const wchar_t *. Why c_str() returns char instead wchar? How can I solve it?

Here is the code:

```
#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include <config.h>
#endif

#include <iostream.h>
#include <string>

typedef basic_string<wchar_t> wstring;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  char pHW[100];
  wstring kk = L"Hello World!";


  wcstombs(pHW,kk.c_str(),100); //kk.c_str() returns char * instead wchar_t

  cout << "Text:[" << pHW << "]" << endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: 2.96 is too old and too non-standard - there are very few good reasons to use it

Comment: The GCC team never released any such version. What you refer to is a bastard of EGCC and GCC, I believe, shipped with some Redhat, if I remember correctly. It is more than ten years old and there is no reason to use it any longer. Please upgrade to something at least halfway recent.

Comment: Maybe you would get a more useful solution if you said why you think you need to use this version. Then people may be able to suggest how to use a recent version in your circumstances.

Comment: Yes it's a Redhat 7.3. The problem is that I can't change the compiler or distribution. The application run in a very old hardware (prehistoric) and only Redhat 7.3 or older distributions are supported.

Comment: Well then you can't use `wstring`

Answer (score 1):

Generally, my advice would have been like the comments above; that you shouldn't use that dated a compiler and standard library. But it seems like you don't have any other options.

If your only problem is `c_str()` (i.e. other methods and operators work fine,) you can check the `basic_string` implementation to see how they implement the `c_str` themselves.

If it's something like simply returning the address of the underlying memory, only cast to `char *` (which implies a contiguous memory block,) then you can cast the returned pointer right back to `wchar_t const *` and it probably will work out fine.

If the underlying memory block for `basic_string` is non-contiguous, then you can always simulate the `c_str()` operation yourself, by iterating over the string and copying the `wchar_t`s out. Of course, this might not be acceptable performance-wise, but I'm sure you can figure things out on a case-by-case basis.

If your problem is more general, you *might* be able to find 3rd-party C++ Standard Library implementations for your compiler and distro that are more conformant (e.g. STLport, etc.)

I'm assuming that you don't want to implement `std::wstring` yourself, since it's obviously always an option.

Answer (score 1):

If you need `std::wstring` with an old compiler/library not implementing the C++ standard and not providing it, you need to implement a sufficient version yourself. Depending on you needs it may not be too complicated to implement a version, e.g., in terms of `std::vector<wchar_t>`. Most of the `std::basic_string<...>` functions can be implemented quite easily using algorithms.

That said, if you are hoping to get iostreams working for `wchar_t` pretty much all hope is lost! If I really had to do something like that I *might* unearth [my standard library](http://www.dietmar-kuehl.de/cxxrt/) implementation and try to get it to compile on this gcc. It won't contain an implementation of `std::basic_string<...>` if I recall correctly but it would contain streams for `wchar_t`.

Personally I think `wchar_t` and anything related to it (as well as `char16_t` and `char32_t`) is the wrong direction: use UTF-8 in `std::string` and define necessary operations for that. `wchar_t` doesn't solve any problem but does create new ones which didn't exist without it (and, yes, I know that Microsoft got tricked by the Unicode promises to use it everywhere - for programners targeting Windows to suffer).

Answer (score 0):

You say you are stuck using that version because :

- you have an application that runs on a prehitoric hardware
- this hardware only supports RH7.3 or older versions

IMHO there are still to paths to experiment :

- virtualization : a virtual machine generally presents simple hardware to the system and we use that to support old application, so you could try to install your old application on a more recent RH version - limit : the application must not be itself dependant from a specialized hardware component that the virtualization cannot emulate
- install on a particular user home a recent (decent) gcc distribution an use it to build your program. It is more or less what some windows developper do with mingw - limit : you must be able to separate developpement from this new program from older ones.